# Virtual StringTreeView Component primary column editing and selection issue

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have created a Virtual StringTreeview component with multiple columns.  Most columns including the primary [0] column are set as coEditable = true.  I have a set up a test with 20 nodes. Once started I can successfully edit the primary column for multiple nodes provided I point to the primary column to pick it. However, once I have selected another node by pointing at another column, I can no longer edit the primary column text on any node. When I select a new row pointing to the primary column, the focus shifts to the selected row, but the previous column used is highlighted instead of the primary column just selected. IF I select a row using any other column, the focus shifts to the correct column and I can edit the string.

TreeOptions.EditOPtions is set to toDefaultEdit. IN addition, the column also contains an image (although I do not see how that changes anything).

Can anyone shed light on any additional settings required or steps I have missed to control focus properly?

EDIT: Added current settings

**VStringTree Options:**

Auto Options = [toAutoDropExpand,toAutoScrollOnExpand,toAutoSort,toAutoTristateTracking,toAutoDeleteMovedNodes,toDisableAutoscrollOnFocus,toAutoChangeScale]

Edit Options = toDefaultEdit

Selection Options = [toExtendedFocus]

Misc. Options = [toEditable,toFullRepaintOnResize,toInitOnSave,toToggleOnDblClick,toWheelPanning,toEditOnClick]

String Options = [toSaveCaptions,toAutoAcceptEditChange]

**Header Options:**
[hoColumnResize,hoDblClickResize,hoDrag,hoHotTrack,hoShowSortGlyphs,hoVisible]

**Column Options:**
[coAllowClick,coEnabled,coParentBidiMode,coParentColor,coResizable,coShowDropMark,coVisible,coEditable]

Comment: Have you included `toGridExtensions` in the `MiscOptions` property set of the tree? If yes, could you include your current settings of the tree in your question, please?

Comment: @Victoria I added my option settings. No toGridExtensions is false.